# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218 error occured in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

I am trying to build the controller that saves the image in my public folder using image intervention. I have used **Cropit** jquery plugin for image cropping and use **ajax**. The error **" MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218"** occurs.Below are my controller ,routes and view.

**CropController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Image;

class CropController extends Controller
{
    public function crop(Request $request){
        $img = $request->image_data;
        $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
        $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
        $data = base64_decode($img);
        Image::make($data)->save('images/images.jpg');
        dd("image saved in images/images.jpg");
    }
}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::post('/image-crop',[
    'uses'=>'CropController@crop',
    'as'=>'image-crop',
]);
```

**welcome.blade.php**

```
<body>
    <form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="{{Session::token()}}" name="_token">
      <div class="image-editor">
        <input type="file" class="cropit-image-input">
        <div class="cropit-preview"></div>
        <div class="image-size-label">
          Resize image
        </div>
        <input type="range" class="cropit-image-zoom-input">
        <input type="hidden" name="imagedata" class="hidden-image-data" />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>

      </div>
    </form>



    <script>

    var url1="{{route('image-crop')}}";
      $(function() {
        $('.image-editor').cropit();

        $('form').submit(function() {
            //event.preventDefault();
          // Move cropped image data to hidden input

          var imageData = $('.image-editor').cropit('export');
          $('.hidden-image-data').val(imageData);

          // Print HTTP request params
          var formValue = $(this).serialize();

            $.ajax({
               type:'post',
               data:formValue,
               url: '/image-crop',
               success: function(data){
               $('#result-data').text('New file in: images/'+data);
               $('#crop').show();
              }

         })
            .done(function(){
                window.location.href=""+'/image-crop';
            });          


          return true;
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
```

How to solve that error ?
Thank you

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` prevents the normal submit, which I think since you don't have an `action` attribute defined on your form tries to submit to the self (current page) which of course doesn't allow post request as per the routes defined. So try after removing '//' (comment out) on line `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: Just to ask the dumb question, are you sure you are posting to the correct URL? what does the network tab say in Firefox or Chrome?
EDIT: I think you are posting through the form, but I doesn't have an action, so its posting to the URL at which it currently is.
EDIT 2: Im almost certain you are posting through the form, or els you would have gotten a csrf token error, as you need to implement the X-CSRF-TOKEN header in the ajaxsetup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Try to add this metatag on your layout
`<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

Also in your ajax request add this `$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
});`

Let me know if it works!.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-x-csrf-token